# EF Can't Find Database on Production

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**Info**

Project is ASP.NET Core 5.0, ORM is EF, DB is SQL Server

**Problem**

On Development, our database is accessible but on production its not!

**Connection String**

Is set in `appsettings.json` and its:

```
"MyConnectionString": "Data Source=MyDomain.com;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD"
```

When we run the project in Visual Studio with this connection string, everything is fine, but it fails when it's published to the host.

The error is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says the connection string is not valid - the production machine does not see/have access to MyDomain.com

Comment: The first thing you have to check is whether the production machine has access to "mydomain.com" - is it on internal network? Is it accessible openly from the internet? Is the development machine maybe on the same network as the database server, but production machine is on different network and thus does not have access to the database?

Comment: Or is the database on the same machine as the application and since the name of the server changed (with maybe a different database, username and password too?)

Comment: If you use a Windows server, you can use a UDL file to test the connection to the database. go to your server and  follow these steps to create a .udl file [Link](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB70929)

Comment: thanks all dude, our production environment is global host and can't access them, I send ticket to host's support to check the connection between the app server and db server.